# Rank of two linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two linear functions $f$ and $g$ in an finite Vectorspace with dimension of *n*. Also $ f $ and $g$ both $V \to V $

I should proof that if $ f \circ g = 0 $ then $ rank(f) + rank(g)  \le n $

Does this mean $f = 0$ and $ g = 0 $ well then the rank always have to be 0,
but this what about $f=-1$ and $g = 1 $ what could I say about the rank of the two functions? It has be $ \le n $ for each but how does the operator $ \circ $ affect it? Normaly I would say $ Rank(f+g) = rank(f) + rank(g) $

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention $ f : V \to V $ - why is this proof trivial? Well I hope it will be trivial to me some day but right now it leaves me puzzled

Comment: You misunderstand to notion of function (map). $f$ and $g$ are functions, e.g. $f(x)=2x$, $g(x)=-3x$. $f\circ g$ is a composition of functions. In your example, $f=-1$, $g=1$ are not functions, but elements of $V$.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of something else when I said it was trivial, although it is still quite easy, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ker}{ker}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rk}$

Let the image $f$ have a basis $(\vec e_1 ,...,\vec e_k)$ and the image of $g$ have a basis $(\vec b_1,...,\vec b_l)$. Then by saying $f \circ g=0$ we are saying that $f(\vec b_i)=0\, \forall \,i$ and thus the kernel of $f$ contains the vectors $(\vec b_1,...,\vec b_l)$. This means that $\dim(\ker(f))\ge \rk(g)=l$  which from the dimension theorem:
$$\dim(V)=\rk(f)+\dim(\ker(f))$$
Means that
$$\dim(\ker(f))=\dim(V)-\rk(f)$$
$$=n-\rk(f)\ge \rk(g)$$
And hence
$$n \ge \rk(g)+\rk(f)$$

**Edit**

Just to clarify the notation the function $f \circ g$ is the function such that:
$$f \circ g(\vec v)=f(g(\vec v))$$
I.e. we first apply the function $g$ to the vector $\vec v$ and then take the result and apply the function $f$.